# Shortcut keys for menu items (alt + letter). Is there any convention for namings?

Tags: windows, winforms, user-interface

Is there any official/unofficial/informal convention for alt+key namings ? maybe, Microsoft have some internal document for that thing. Different menu levels and so on ...

http://img256.imageshack.us/img256/2426/shortcutl.jpg
[alt text http://img256.imageshack.us/img256/2426/shortcutl.jpg](http://img256.imageshack.us/img256/2426/shortcutl.jpg)

Comment: Just do what ever makes sense, and what you are used to. For instance, don't make save use the letter 'o' that you would expect to open.

Comment: What you are calling "Shortcut Keys" are actually "Access Keys". The "Shortcut keys" are keyboard combinations that allow the user to execute a command. Typically, "Shortcut Keys" are shown on an associate menu item. In the sample, The access key for "How Do I" is Alt+D and the shortcut key is Ctrl+F1.

Comment: thecoshman, i did this way before. But sometimes maybe collisions, or there are many menu items. I need some standard.

AMissico, ohh, access key. thanks for correction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Microsoft always provides "user guidelines" for an operating system.

*Windows User Experience Interaction Guidelines* at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa511258.aspx.

- Access Keys at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa511502.aspx#accessKeys
- Shortcut Keys at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa511502.aspx#shortcutKeys
- Label [menu item names] at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa511502.aspx#labels

*Design Specifications and Guidelines - Visual Design* at 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms997617.aspx.

*Microsoft Manual of Style for Technical Publications* is helpful. Check out http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Manual_of_Style_for_Technical_Publications.

Comment: Thanks for a detailed answer, AMissico. I marked your answer as useful (green sign).

Answer (score 0):

Typically, unless there are conflicts in a menu you want to pick the letter that corresponds to the most important word in the menu item. For instance, in the linked example, `[A]bout Microsoft Visual Studio` and `Customer [F]eedback Options` each use the letter of the most important part of the item (or what describes it best).

Certain combinations are fairly similar across most apps - for instance, most users expect <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>,<kbd>S</kbd> to be File -> Save, et cetera. These should be fairly obvious if you've used a couple of Windows applications.

Comment: -1: What is obvious to you, is not obvious to everyone else. In addition, you do not just "pick" a letter for the most important word. What is important to you is, again, not important to me. Over the years, we used the letter that most sound like the command (verb) we want. For instance, [A]bout the program, [O]pen the item, [P]rint the item, P[r]operties of the item, and so on.

Comment: @pstanton: lame for you, not for me. The point is, you cannot make assumptions about users based on your (the programmer's) perspective. It is not a good answer.